# Name error global name not defined

Tags: python

I'm getting a NameError: global name 'mapping' is not defined. Where am I going wrong?

```
 class CheckFunction:
     mapping = [6,2,5,5,4,5,6,3,7,6]
     def newFunction(self,code):
        splitting = code.split()
        count = 0
        for n in splitting:
           count += mapping[int(n)]
        return count

 obj = CheckFunction()
 obj.newFunction("13579")
```

Comment: What python version are you using? And where are you using `mapping` in your code?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
class CheckFunction(object):
     def __init__(self):
        self.mapping = [6,2,5,5,4,5,6,3,7,6]
     def newFunction(self,code):
        count = 0
        for n in code:
           count += self.mapping[int(n)]
        return count

obj = CheckFunction()
obj.newFunction("13579")
```

Result:

```
>>> obj.newFunction('13579')
21
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are using `mapping` just like that. You must use it like:

```
self.mapping
```